# Does this inequality about sampling hold?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

$\frac{x+z-1}{x+z+w+y-1}<\frac{x}{x+z} \frac{z}{z+w}+\frac{z}{x+z} \frac{x}{x+y}<\frac{x+z}{x+z+w+y}$, where $x, y, z, w$ are all positive intergers (I believe whether they are intergers are irrelevant).

The background of this inequality is as follows. Suppose there are $x$ male Democrats, $y$ male Republicans, $z$ female Democrats, and $w$ female Republicans. Consider the following sampling method.

1. Randomly draw a person, and then randomly draw another person
2. Randomly draw a person, and then randomly draw another person with another gender
3. Randomly draw a person, put him/her back, and then randomly draw another person

The numbers in the inequality are the probabilities of drawing a Democrat conditional on the first draw being a Democrat.

Answer (score 0):

First off to address your claim in brackets you have to assume $x+y+z+w > 1$, as otherwise
$$
\frac{x+z-1}{x+z+w+y-1} \not< \frac{x+z}{x+z+w+y}.
$$
But with that assumption you get the inequality pretty immediately. In particular letting $a = x+z$ and $b = x+z+w+y$, we have $\frac{a - 1}{b-1} < \frac{a}{b}$, which is equivalently $ab - b < ab - a$, and $b > a$ by positivity of x,y,z,w; implying $\frac{x+z-1}{x+z+w+y-1} < \frac{x+z}{x+z+w+y}$.

Okay, so now to the probabilistic aspect of your question. In order to solve the conditional probability, the first thing you have to do is just assume off the bat that you have selected a Democrat. You correctly computed the probabilities for (1) and (3) but for (2) you have to be a little careful. For instance, if all we have in our population is 5 FD and 5 MR and we selected an FD, then we know the next selection is MR because of the different gender requirement. Thus $\frac{4}{9} = P(1) > P(2) = 0$ in that case, so you don't necessarily that $(1) \subseteq (2)$ like you're assuming.

Formally, this is because although the requirement that you draw someone of the opposite gender looks like a restriction of the probability space, it's actually a change to the sampling mechanism so it doesn't necessarily follow that the probability gets reduced.

The last subtlety here is that for (1) and (3), the probability is independent of the gender of the first Democrat selected, whereas for (2) it's clearly not independent. Hope this helps!